# what is mean by "this code is DRY" in ROR3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I m new to ROR3.0 I was read a lot place saying that is "this code is DRY" or something related to DRY 
I want to know how to make a code DRY ?
Is it necessary my code should be DRY?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself. Also this kind of open ended question doesn't belong on SO ...

Comment: You might be right, but how about some benevolence to the newbie asker? Wikipedia happens not to be an exellent answer in this particular case.

Comment: I thought the article was pretty straight forward, and I actually tried to help him, otherwise I would not have made a quick google search :)

Comment: i asked question here because i need answer from expert and straight forward answer

Comment: @Alberto: Actually, I was reacting to 2 different things: Benevolence comment was for the downvotes, and Wikipedia comment for my dissatisfaction with the state of that Wp page. But fortunately, DavidKennedy already provided link to WikiWiki in his answer below. Still, I consider this a valid SO question, what exactly does it mean DRY.

Comment: Ok since there's a only a -1(actually, +2/-3) on the question, I'll remove my downvote. I thought that this kind of question would have been best asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ though. Edit : can't remove it unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRY stands for Don't Repeat Yourself. If it's possible, it's good practice to use DRY in most coding environments to make it easy to maintain going forward (and stop your copy-paste keys getting worn out!)

I'd suggest wherever code is repeated to extract the common code and extract into a method.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki below is a good place to see where a lot of these shorthand expressions came from:

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself

In this case, 'DRY' simply means 'Don't Repeat Yourself'. This simple guideline leads to writing smaller, better decomposed methods which can be reused in several contents. This in turn leads to easier maintenance, better testability etc.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: Fair point Kev, quick update added.